# Is it necessary to use $ionicPlatform.ready() in every controllers?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

Is it necessary to user $ionicPlatform.ready() in every controllers in ionic. Does it effect controller working? If we doesn't use this will there be effect in functionality of devices?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

if you have any code(native plugin's methods) that need device ready first than you have to put that code in  $ionicplatform.ready()

In other controller you do not need $ionicplatform.ready()

Comment: What are the things I need to mention to use  $ionicplatform.ready() ?

Comment: You just need to inject `$ionicPlatform` in controller in which you are using `$ionicplatform.ready()`

Comment: How to do this in ionic 3 project?